# Simple decorator function in python not working

Tags: python

I am trying to execute the below code in pycharm.

```
def auth_login(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Authenticating......")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper()


@auth_login
def login(username, password):
    print("Successfully logged in:",username)

login('setu', 'setu')
```

Looks pretty straight forward but I getting the below error:
Output :

```
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>     Authenticating......
>       File "C:/Users/611834094/PycharmProjects/PractiseProject/decorators/example3.py",
> line 10, in <module>
>         @auth_login
>       File "C:/Users/611834094/PycharmProjects/PractiseProject/decorators/example3.py",
> line 7, in auth_login
>         return wrapper()
>       File "C:/Users/611834094/PycharmProjects/PractiseProject/decorators/example3.py",
> line 5, in wrapper
>         func(*args, **kwargs)
>     TypeError: login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'
>     
>     Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `return wrapper()` should be `return wrapper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the value of wrapper. Instead just return the function.

```
def auth_login(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Authenticating......")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper # Here was the issue.


@auth_login
def login(username, password):
    print("Successfully logged in:",username)

login('setu', 'setu')
```

Comment: It's not the name, it's the function object itself.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for correcting my mistake. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets while returning wrapper function

```
def auth_login(func):
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Authenticating......")
    func(*args, **kwargs)
# Remove the brackets from wrapper
return wrapper
```